# Trying to get number of rows in sas dataset using syspam

Tags: bash, unix, sas

Below is the shell script to get the number of row in sas dataset.

```
echo -n "Enter path:"
read path

echo -n "Enter dataset:"
read name

{
echo "options nofmterr;"
echo "options symbolgen mprint mlogic;"
echo "libname sasdata '$path' access=readonly ;"
echo "data _null_;"
 echo "file stdout;"
 echo 'set "&sysparm" nobs=nobs;'
 echo "put nobs; stop;"
echo "run; "
} > "$path/test1.sas"

cd $path


var=$(sas test1.sas -sysparm  $path/$name.sas7bdat)
echo [$var ]
```

but after running the script "var" have the below value in text.
[image]

where as I was expecting the result value of "var"  [4472].

I am not sure where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Though, are you running against a SAS grid environment and/or SAS Viya?

Comment: It looks like you're submitting to a grid server given that comment.  I'm not sure if you can turn that off or not, but I'm sure you could parse that, anyway...

Comment: Joe, I am using the SAS with unix platform.

Comment: That's obvious, but, you are running on a SAS grid server, right?  And are you using bash, ksh, what, to write this?

Comment: Yes, It's a sas grid server and using bash to write the script.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the shell you're using, so this will be without code, but generally speaking, you should simply parse the returned string and retrieve the value from it.  That's just SAS putting messages in STDOUT; it will put various messages there, including errors and similar.

If you want to make it really easy to parse out, put it in brackets or something else that makes it very easy to grep, perhaps changing

```
put nobs;
```

to

```
put "Obs Count:[" nobs "]";
```

or similar.

You should also probably include some error handling here, checking that string to make sure it doesn't indicate there was an error submitting the code or similar.

Comment: I see you did eventually mention it was bash; if you need help with the bash part of things, add a comment, but I assume string parsing is fairly trivial for you otherwise.